# Is there a Way to stop an Azure virtual Machine after two hours?

Tags: powershell, webhooks, azure-virtual-machine, azure-automation

I already have written a PowerShell Script, which starts an Azure Virtual Machine over a POST request to Azure Automation. For cost reasons, those Machines should automatically stop after two hours.

Is there a Way/Function to do this easily?

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://www.herlitz.nu/2016/01/02/how-to-stop-deallocate-an-azure-vm-at-a-given-time-using-powershell/) is what you are looking for?

Comment: Hello Theo,
no, I need a way to start something like a timer in Azure which stops the started VM. All should work out of one Script without Access to the VM. (The Script should work for all requested Machines)

Comment: You can use Azure Automation solution - Start/Stop VM solution. It supports we schedule cam to start or stop. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-solution-vm-management

Comment: Is your requirement a daily task or a one time task?

Comment: My requirement is a task, which is triggered from a Website or a PowerShell script.

Comment: What I want to know is that if the task runs every day or just run only once?

Comment: The task runs not every Day. It runs if someone starts the script. It could be every day, but it could also be just once in a month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your requirement, you need to calculate the duration that the VM running yourself. You can get the event time that the last start time when the VM is in the running time. It's the UTC time. Then calculate the duration up to now yourself. Here is the Azure CLI command to get the event time:

```
az vm get-instance-view -g yourResourceGroup -n yourVM --query instanceView.statuses
```

The screenshot of the result here:

[image]

Or you can filter the activity log to get the last event "Start Virtual Machine" time. Below is the Azure CLI command:

```
az monitor activity-log list --resource-id yourVM_resourceId --query "[?operationName.localizedValue == 'Start Virtual Machine'].eventTimestamp" --max-events 1
```

I think it should be an interval query task to last for two hours as you need. In my own opinion, it should run in the script that starts the VM.